# Array as the options for a switch statment

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement

I remember from way back at university using a switch with 'binary search' or 'binary switch'. Something like that, My google foo is broken today. Anyway it goes down like this: You define an array of possible options (Strings usually), some magic happens, and those options in the array become the cases in the switch happens. I do remember that they had to be in alphabetical order for this to work. Can you help me remember the magic? Even a name of what I should be looking at would be fantastic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is an [Enum](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

From the link above...

```
public enum Day {
    SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, 
    THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY 
}

public class EnumTest {

    Day day;

    public EnumTest(Day day) {
        this.day = day;
    }

    public void tellItLikeItIs() {
         switch (day) {
            case MONDAY:
                 System.out.println("Mondays are bad.");
                 break;

            case FRIDAY:
                 System.out.println("Fridays are better.");
                 break;

            case SATURDAY:
            case SUNDAY:
                 System.out.println("Weekends are best.");
                 break;

            default:
                 System.out.println("Midweek days are so-so.");
                 break;
        }
    }

    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean gperf?  Or possibly you were referring to the theory (hashing) in general?

http://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I wouldn't abuse a switch in such a way (even if I could). Try you might, you won't be able to get arrays to work in a switch statement because it only allows constant values in the case lines. Are you sure that you are not thinking of some pattern like below or an enumeration?

```
final int RED = 0;
final int YELLOW = 1;
final int BLUE = 2;
final int GREEN = 3;

String[] colors = new String[] { "red", "yellow", "blue", "green" };

switch (color) {
    case RED:
        System.out.println(colors[RED]);
        break;
    case YELLOW:
        System.out.println(colors[YELLOW]);
        break;
    ...the rest
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an Enum without a switch looks like:

```
public enum Day {
    SUNDAY {
      public String tellItLikeItIs() {
        return "Weekends are best.";
      }
    },
    MONDAY {
      public String tellItLikeItIs() {
        return "Mondays are bad.";
      }
    }, 
    TUESDAY, 
    WEDNESDAY, 
    THURSDAY, 
    FRIDAY {
      public String tellItLikeItIs() {
        return "TGI Friday.";
      }
    }, 
    SATURDAY {
      public String tellItLikeItIs() {
        return "Weekends are best.";
      }
    }

    public String tellItLikeItIs() {
       return "Midweek days are so-so.";
    }
}

public class TodayIs{
    public static void main(String... args) {
         Day day = Day.valueOf(args[0].toUppercase());
         System.out.println(day.tellItLikeItIs());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public enum Day {
    SUNDAY ("sundays are this"),
    MONDAY ("mondays are that"), 
    TUESDAY ("blah"), 
    WEDNESDAY ("blah"), 
    THURSDAY ("blah"), 
    FRIDAY ("blah"), 
    SATURDAY ("more blah");

    private final String tell;

    public Day(String tell){
       this.tell = tell;
    }
    public String tellItLikeItIs() {
       return this.tell;
    }
}

public class TodayIs{
    public static void main(String... args) {
         Day day = Day.valueOf(args[0].toUppercase());
         System.out.println(day.tellItLikeItIs());
```

I'm new to java enums, but I think this should work too.

Comment: Yes, that works too. Only it really has nothing to do with the question anymore (neither does Peter Lawrey's answer).

Answer (score 0):

***If your choice is to use enum and your enum collection is of a big size use:***

**MAGIC:**

If you are working in *eclipse*, it will do a "magic" for you just you need to write the following (taking into consideration the accepted answer's code):

```
switch (day) {
}
```

select the `switch` and press *Ctrl + 1* and the magic works! (all the `enum` values will populate in the `case` sections of your `switch` block)